# Terminal-based snake game: input thread manipulates output

Tags: ruby, multithreading, terminal

I'm writing a snake game for the terminal, i.e. output via print.

The following works just fine:

```
while status[snake_monad] do
  print to_string draw canvas, compose_all([
    frame,
    specs,
    snake_to_hash(snake[snake_monad])
  ])

  turn! snake_monad, get_dir
  move! snake_monad, specs

  sleep 0.25
end
```

But I don't want the `turn!`ing to block, of course. So I put it into a new Thread and let it loop:

```
Thread.new do
  loop do
    turn! snake_monad, get_dir
  end
end

while status[snake_monad] do
  ...
  # no turn! here
  ...
end
```

Which also works logically (the snake is turning), but the output is somehow interspersed with newlines. As soon as I kill the input thread (`^C`) it looks normal again.

So why and how does the thread have any effect on my output?
And how do I work around this issue? 
(I don't know much about threads, even less about them in ruby. Input and output concurrently on the same terminal make the matter worse, I guess...)

Also (not really important): Wanting my program as pure as possible, would it be somewhat easily possible to get the input non-blockingly while passing everything around?

Thank you!

Comment: Worse? Never, *ever* let two threads to console IO. It will end badly. And if you try to put a mutex around STDIN and STDOUT...I shudder to see the code.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but it doesn't work either. The closest I get is: the frozen first frame, where I can type and `^C` ... it then will do the directions I typed. Any other combinations had the original (bad) effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want **non-blocking** IO - you want **unbuffered** IO.

There's no need for threads, here - you just need to put your terminal into the right mode and then wait for the keypress on the main event loop.

Here's a completely ridiculous example.

```
require 'io/wait'

def ping
  term = `stty -g`
  `stty raw -echo cbreak`
  loop do
    if STDIN.ready?
      #command thy snake!
      ret = STDIN.getc 
    end
    if ret
      #process the snake command if there was one
      STDOUT.write("you told the snake to #{ret}\n")
    else
      #slither around bitin' fools and hustling apples.
    end
  end
ensure
  `stty #{term}`
end
```

Comment: I think, I'm already using something equivalent: On 1.9.3, I `require 'io/console'` and that provides `STDIN.getch` and `STDIN.noecho(&:getch)`, with `getch` being unbuffered. Anyway, this doesn't seem to be the problem as it's working fine without the thread ...

Comment: And with blocking I meant that my program still has to wait for some key to be pressed and read, which I suppose your code has to do, too; or how else does it get its input?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. This doesn't wait for a key press before updating the snake position. If you didn't turn, then the snake goes straight on.

Comment: OK, I'm sorry. I tried your example and it works in isolation, but not in my program, it just freezes, completely. I guess the cause to be the concurrent printing ...

Comment: Probably - outputting to the console from two threads like that is a recipe for difficulty, you need to mutex around any of the IO code.

Comment: No difference. For the time being, I'll keep my dirty solution, as it actually works quite well. I'll figure this one out another time. It surely is good to know that this basically is possible. Thanks.

Comment: I got it working now, without threads. It's not perfect, though. Now I have to disable echoing but for the printing or else the keystrokes that don't get caught by the input function are printed and destroy the frame.

Answer (score 0):

I found a dirty solution:

I just had to add a carriage return (`\r`) after each newline in the `to_string` function, so everything that gets printed after it will be overwritten. Since it was a newline, it loses its effect. Everything seems fine now.

But I'd much rather know why this happens and fix it (if possible) cleanly.